# How to deny the use of dangerous PHP functions?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How To Disable Dangerous Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865020/php-how-to-disable-dangerous-functions)

Hi, this is my situation: I must let my clients enter PHP code, but only safe functions like string function, date function etc. So I need the danger PHP functions list to remove them by using string replace before save to PHP file. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget it. Reliable function whitelisting is not possible in php. Example:

```
$x = 'e' . str_replace('y', 'x', 'yec');
...lots of code...
$x('format c:');
```

*realistic* options are

- disabling functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)
- sandboxing (see [Recommendations for sandboxing inside PHP5 or alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241168/recommendations-for-sandboxing-inside-php5-or-alternatives))

Comment: @stereofrog That's why I am not recommending it. Feel free to edit my answer to make it less confusing. I am terrible at explanations.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Reliable function **whitelisting** is impossible in PHP"? Because blacklisting is possible using disable_functions.

Comment: Didn't notice that, I'll edit it then :p.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can only use a black-list approach:

- http://es2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions
- http://es2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-classes

Of course, you have to consider how feasible it is to maintain an updated list of all builtin functions defined by all the possible extensions.

<del>Another possibility I can think of is writing a simple tokenizer:</del>

http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

You can then check the functions used against a white list.

**Update:** I was under the wrong impression that `token_get_all()` would identify function calls but it actually doesn't. They're all `T_STRING`s.

Comment: +1, i dont understand why people tend to over complicate issues like these, over-compicating it wont make it safer, stick to the original methods such as `disable-functions` and `disable-classes`

Comment: @stereofrog, I've figured out what you meant (you don't really say) and edited my post accordingly.

Comment: PHP.net's token documentation is pretty lacking. They leave out certain tokens and also incorrectly define a few tokens--either that or their usage by `token_get_all()` and by PHP's warning/error messages are different, and they are going by the latter.

Comment: @stereofrog: of course, you're right about that. It's not even worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

The most secure and easy to maintain option will be to program a dedicated "mini-language" in php. You can make it a subset of php, or make it look like Excel formulas, or even invent your own one. This way you'll always have the full control of what's happening.

//

just for fun, here's a small Lisp for you

```
function lisp($x) {

    if(is_string($x)) {
        $re = '~\(([^()]*)\)~';
        while(preg_match($re, $x))
            $x = preg_replace_callback($re, 'lisp', $x);
        return trim($x);
    }

    $x = preg_split('~\s+~', $x[1]);
    $e = array_shift($x);
    if(!$x)
        return is_numeric($e) ?  floatval($e) : $e;

    switch($e) {
        case '+':  return lisp($x[0]) + lisp($x[1]);
        case '-':  return lisp($x[0]) - lisp($x[1]);
        case '*':  return lisp($x[0]) * lisp($x[1]);
        case '/':  return lisp($x[0]) / lisp($x[1]);

        case 'concat':  return lisp($x[0]) . lisp($x[1]);
    }

    return function_exists($e) ?
        call_user_func_array($e, array_map('lisp', $x)) : '';
}

$input = '
    (strtolower 
        (concat
            (strrev olleh) 
            (+ 22 20)))';

echo lisp($input); // hello42
```

;))

Comment: That's potentially a *lot* of work.

Comment: You could make a dynamic-scoped lisp-1. You don't have to tell them it's lisp. Or if you prefer, you could go get LIME for PHP and implement infix algebra, perhaps inside [square brackets] and make something that looks like TCL. Why does it have to look like PHP?

Comment: or You can write a parser of a subset of PHP in PHP and run only selected functions! :D

Answer (score 1):

Giving users the possibility to enter PHP code is really dangerous. Consider all other options before implementing this. Some kind of PHP-code builder. Inspired on a Query builder.

If you decide to allow PHP code by the clients, it is better to use a whitelist. <strike>You should use regular expressions to extract these functions from the posted code.</strike>

Comment: PHP is not a regular language.

Comment: @Gumbo: Please explain what that has to do with this situation?

Comment: @Stegeman You can't use regular expressions on a language that's not regular.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but he says enter, which, in my understanding, means that he will post the code. In that case the code is just a string and it is possible to use regular expressions on a string isn't it?

If he wants to upload the code I know I'm wrong. Just trying to understand and learn a little :)

Comment: @Stegeman: Sure you can use regular expressions on strings. But the data in the string (i.e. PHP code) is not a regular language. Just think about removing the function call of `foobar` in a PHP code like this: `<?php echo "calling foobar()"; foobar();` Here you cannot simply use something like `/\bfoobar\s*\(\s*\)/` to find that function call.

Comment: @Gumbo, thanks for the lesson. +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are expected to do is extremely hard work if you want to get it right. I would start by [parsing](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) the entered php code, checking each called function, disallowing [backticks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) altogether, etc.

In other words: If you want to allow a sub-set of PHP you must implement your own [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) (even if PHP provides you a [parser](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) out of the box).